# Local cassandra for testing purposes getting slower over time

Tags: cassandra

I do know that it's a cassandra anti-pattern to delete rows (and more so – doing it frequently), but in my simple use case I have a local cassandra (single instance, replication factor set to 1) that I use for unit tests, which drop all tables before running, naturally to perform the tests with a *clean slate*.

Over time, the performance of this cassandra instance degraded extremely. It surprised me a bit that dropping the keyspaces althogether didn't help at all. Only by manually deleting everything in cassandra data directory I managed to recover all the performance.

This solution is quite fine for me as I don't care for the test data I delete over and over again, but it certainly feels a bit weird to have to delete these things manually on file system. Is there a better way to deal with such situation? Or am I going about this whole case completely wrong?

Comment: have you tried ccm? https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm makes it so simple to create/delete clusters and you can easily compile different versions of cassandra for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the little information provided, I will provide some info:

First, deleting data creates tombstones in cassandra.  The default behavior is to keep these tombstones for 10 days, set by the variable gc_grace_seconds.

Given you only have 1 node and don't care about the data once you delete it, you could set gc_grace_seconds to zero.  You also could make sure to run compaction after you do a lot of deletes.

Documentation here:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html

Lastly, there is a feature known as TTL, Time To Live.  You could use that instead of deleting and let the database do the "deletes" once the data expires.  If you go this route, I would still set gc_grace_seconds to zero and run compactions (via an hourly cronjob since its a dev environment).

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestions and see what happens (I actually did the compactions and it didn't help, but I am still quite new with cassandra and maybe I did something wrong, so I will do some further reading on this)